# Tableau Desktop- Does it require Tableau Server ?

Tags: tableau-api

Does Tableau Desktop Professional require Tableau Server? I know they are two different products that are shipped separately, but I am wondering what your business requirements would be if you were to use both Desktop and Server?

Basically, what can you do with Desktop and Server that you cannot do with just Desktop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need Tableau Server for the use of Tableau Desktop!

The advantage of Tableau server comes in if you want to use collaborative features and distribute dashboards easily inside the organisation.
You can upload workbooks to the server for colleagues to consume, you can restrict the access to make data only available to certain people. You can also store data extracts on Tableau server which is often quicker to access than using a standard connection to an SQL DB for example. Without server you are able to connect to these sources but obviously everybody who wants to use the data needs access to the database or system you are using. Which might not be wanted, think about giving all your 5000 employees access to an SAP warehouse versus just extracting one source to the server and making it available to everybody.
Depending on your licensing model you might also be able to host your dashboards and embed them for example in your companies website or intranet for everybody to look at.
You can also do modifications of workbooks on the server without needing to have Tableau desktop installed and you can access the dashboards on mobile devices (iOS for now Android in the near future) I you wish to.

That's the quick run down of the main features. There are lots more and obviously more details to consider.

Comment: This is great. Thanks @Alexander. You've touched on this, but do you know if you can connect to your own SQL databases within your organisation without using Tableau Server?  
Thanks

Comment: Yes you can. You can connect to any source Tableau supports without having Tableau Server. However everybody who wants to connect needs to have access to the DB. With Tableau Server you could extract just certain views or tables and make them available only to certain people.

Comment: There are a few license levels for Tableau Desktop. Tableau Desktop Professional Edition can connect directly to many databases. Tableau Desktop Personnel Edition can only connect to CSV, Excel and I think MS Access, perhaps a few others.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

**tableau desktop** is for creating some visual thing from the raw data like flat file or the data which is on the server,

and beside that **tableau server** browser based used to publish from tableau desktop and manage the dashboards through mobile and browser. 
hope you got the answer between tableau desktop and server.

Answer (score 2):

On Tableau Desktop you can create advanced calculations and allows you use all the appliction features.

On the other side, the new versions of Tableau Server the Worksheets editor was improved, but still have some limitations when you need to connect with some Data Sources and when have to use advanced features.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, These 2 are two different products.Please find below definitions in layman terms:

Normally **Desktop** is used to create all different visualizations by connecting /blending different data sources & its mandatory for every one to use this

However, **Server** is not a mandatory product but you can use this to store your daily data (which will help you to run your queries faster as compared to when you connect to some external database or source)

Hoping this will help everyone to understand.
Thanks!